# С чего лучше начать свой путь в программировании на python

Tags: python

Всегда очень интересовался программированием, но, увы, получил диплом юриста, и какое то время даже работал. Сейчас решил все-таки конкретно засесть за это дело. Свой путь решил начать с *Python*. 
[Скачал](https://theoryandpractice.ru/courses/29795-razrabotchik-na-python) данный курс.

Лектор довольно хорошо и подробно все объясняет, но, к сожалению, для человека с 0 знаниями, остаётся довольно много вопросов, на которые сложно найти ответы.

Хотел бы узнать, какие книги купить или какие курсы ещё скачать, чтобы полностью во всем разобраться?

И где ещё можно задавать вопросы новичка, чтобы действительно получать ответы?

P.S. Гуглом пользоваться умею, но книг и курсов слишком много, к сожалению, многие из них не прибавят мне никаких знаний.

Comment: Попробуйте начать с pythontutor.ru. Теория без практики - ничто. В процессе выполнения задач на этом сайте у Вас возникнет куча вопросов, в процессе просмотра решений (их показывают после того как сами решили) вопросов прибавится, в процессе поиска ответов на все эти вопросы Вы наткнетесь на интересные идиомы, которые Вам тоже захочется понять... Ну в общем слово-за-слово... )))

Comment: Тяжело будет юристу переучиваться на программиста.